# How derives works with value classes in Scala3?

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-3

I have a value class `ItemId` and I want to take advantage of `derives` for JsonCodec

I would like to do something like this:

```
final case class ItemId(value: Long) extends AnyVal derives JsonCodec
```

Unfortunatelly, this code doesn't compile and I come with work around for a moment:

```
final case class ItemId(value: Long) extends AnyVal
object ItemId:
  given codec: JsonCodec[ItemId] = JsonCodec[Long].transform(ItemId(_), _.value)
```

**Question:**
Could you explain why it doesn't work and how I can make use of `derives` with value classes in Scala3?

Comment: AFAIK no library magically handles `AnyVal`s, it's more like adding a special case after checking that `A <: AnyVal` so that you can convert to and from the only value pretending that it's an alias. Unless this `JsonCodec` has a special handle for `AnyVal`s (you haven't mention from which library this comes from) `case class` extending `AnyVal` is just a product of 1, with possibly less runtime overhead, but the same structure as any any other product.

Comment: BTW also `AnyVal` is mostly deprecated in **Scala 3**, rather just use an `opaque type`

Comment: Another things is that `derives` is not magical, `class A derives X` inserts `X.derived[A]` into `A` companion, so there has to be `derived` method in `X` (imported extension methods count as well).